# CountIF beginning and month end

Tags: excel, countif

I am working on Excel 2010

I need to summarize open purchase orders at the start and end of the month.

The data on a different tab will have all the purchase orders with an open date in 1 column and a closed date in the other (sometimes it may be blank if not closed)

I want to know how many orders were open at the 1st Jan and then how many were open at the 31st.

I have tried some countifs but not getting desired results, as I can see the new cases opened or closed but the number of active PO.

The expected output is:

```
|--------|---------------|
| 01/Jan | X orders open |
|--------|---------------|
| 31/Jan | X orders open |
```

I need to be separated by beginning and end of month

`=COUNTIFS(C2:C6,"<="&E9,D2:D6,">="&E9)`

Where C2:C6 is the open data and E9 is where I have just put 1 Jan 2019.
D2:D6 is the closed date the result I am getting is just 1 when the active orders are two.

At the moment I am just picking up orders created on 1 Jan but what I want is order no. open as at 1 Jan

EDIT-

```
|   | A | B | C           | D           | E         |
|---|---|---|-------------|-------------|-----------|
| 1 |   |   | P.O. raised | Date Closed |           |
| 2 |   |   | 02-dec-18   |             |           |
| 3 |   |   | 12-Oct-18   | 02-Jan-19   |           |
| 4 |   |   | 01-Apr-18   |             |           |
| 5 |   |   | 1-Jan-2019  |             |           |
| 6 |   |   |             |             |           |
| 7 |   |   |             |             |           |
| 8 |   |   |             |             |           |
| 9 |   |   |             |             | 01-Jan-19 |
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data and a condition you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try? You are not showing any effort.

Comment: sorry to new to this - copy and paste is messing the formula but data is as below
 
formula used is '=COUNTIFS(C2:C6,"<="&E9,D2:D6,">="&E9)  C2:C6 is the open data and E9 is where I have just put 1 Jan 2019 -  and d2:d6 is the closed date 
the result i am getting is just 1 when the active orders are two.  At the moment I am just picking up orders created on 1 Jan but what I want is order no. open as at 1 Jan
   
edit- sorry pasting data the format is messed up but basically column c2:c6 is open dates and d2:d6 closed dates  - e9 is date of 1 Jan 19.

Comment: I already edit your post, please check it...